# Remove objects with a duplicate property from List in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I Have a list and I want to create a new one without records with duplicate values

```
public List<links> results = new List<links>();
public List<links> final_results = new List<links>();
public class links
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int place { get; set; }
}
```

results gets it's values during code. Same record may occur with unique **Place** property but other properties are the same. I want to ommit duplicate records which have duplicate value in the url, title and description.
I wrote this code but nothing changed:

```
     final_results = results .GroupBy(n => n.url).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

but when I bind my repeator to this new list nothing has changed.
how can I ommit this duplicte value?

Comment: I don't believe that nothing has changed because it should work. But it's not clear if you only want to check the single property `url` or if the combination of the three properties `url`,`title `, `description` is equal.

Comment: Can you post some example data? Do you check the contents of `final_results` or something else? If you check an HTML control you may be binding to the wrong data.

Comment: @mary, I think what you want is a [DistinctBy() Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property) extension method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think it is not important which property I check because just Place property is unique .

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i use a Repeater and bind it to the list I want to ommit duplicate records

Comment: @jmb.mage distinctby() property is used for records which have all properties the same but in my case I should check some properties

Comment: You could write a class that implements IEqualityComparer<links> by comparing on the properties you are interested in, then use the Linq Distinct() overload that takes the comparer as a parameter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to suppress records with equality in 3 preperties `url`,`title`and `description`, you have to group by all of them:

```
final_results = results.GroupBy(n => new {n.url, n.description, n.title})
                       .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: @mary you're binding the repeater to `Repeater.DataSource = final_results; Repeater.DataBind();` ?

Comment: @fubo as u said Rep.DataSource = final_results;
            Rep.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

Umm, you can just do:

```
var results = results.DistinctBy(x=> x.url);
```

Or if you want to exclude by multiple fields, simpliest is this:

```
var results = results.DistinctBy(x=> x.url + "," + x.title + "," + x.description);
```

If you want to do it properly - just override Equal and GetHashCode methods of your object and put your values in HashSet.

For DistinctBy to work, you can increase your .NET version or just use MoreLINQ.

Comment: tnx exactly I cant use DistinctBy for results

Comment: Then just write your own. There is plenty implementations here on stackoverflow. Including slow comparing distinction.

Answer (score 0):

try using Except extension method over the Links

```
final_results = results.Except(--duplicate criteria--)
```

Comment: what should i write in criteria ? i want to ommit duplicate values?